# GoLang Unmarshal Extreme Nested Struct

Tags: json, go, types, marshalling, unmarshalling

Given the following structs

```
type UpdateConcert struct {
    FullConcert FullConcert
    Fields    map[string]interface{}
}

type FullConcert struct {
    DomConcert       *dom.Concert
    DomSingerID string `json:"domSingerID"`
    DomSingerGroupID string `json:"domSingerGroupID"`
}
```

With the dom.Concert being too large to post but contains int64, int, more nested struct slices, strings, string slices, and time pointers for a total of 90 fields on the dom.Concert (not including the lower nested structs). Also, all json tags are present on both the dom.Concert as well as all nested structs on it.

When doing:

```
    var arrayToUnmarshalInto []UpdateConcert
    var bytes []byte
    bytes, err = json.Marshal(concerts)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to marshal concerts")
    }

    byteLength := len(bytes)
    str := string(bytes[:byteLength])
    err = json.Unmarshal(bytes, &arrayToUnmarshalInto)
    if err != nil {
        return errors.Wrap(err, "Failed to unmarshal concerts")
    }
    fmt.Printf("%v", str)
    fmt.Printf("%v", arrayToUnmarshalInto)
    return nil
```

While using the standard json.Marshal from the "encoding/json" package we can get a valid byte slice back, and when casting to a string from the byte slice we see the expected stringified JSON. However, the arrayToUnmarshalInto produces an empty slice. And when inspecting an individual UpdateConcert struct we see only default values and nil. However, when iterating over a map[string]inteface{} that we have unmarshaled into, we can successfully print all values.

How would one go about writing a custom unmarshal for such a varied and deeply nested struct?

Comment: At first glance, it looks like your struct is causing a disconnect. `DomConcert  *dom.Concert` makes the parser look for a `Concert` object in the JSON with the name `"DomConcert"`. e.g. `{"DomConcert": {...}}`. Is that what you intend?

Comment: According to the string we were able to print out, the JSON string we are seeing is along the lines of `{"FullConcert":{"DomConcert":{...}...} ... }`

Comment: Based off what we are seeing, the JSON string is in the expected format for the object we are passing in. However, when attempting to Unmarshal that back into a GoLang struct, it is unable to parse it properly.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping it was that simple... It is still likely a disconnect somewhere based on the fact that it doesn't throw an error. The Unmarshaller can take care of arbitrarily nested structs, so just the deep nesting itself isn't an issue, unless of course there is a recursive issue, but then it would simply loop forever.

Comment: Unfortunately no, it is not simple. The marshal did its job perfectly from what I was able to read off the stringified json. The fault lies with the unmarshaler currently. I am assuming that a custom unmarshaler is required for this to work properly?

Comment: That's possible, but it may be difficult to determine __for what struct__ to write it for. Without the actual definition, the only thing I can tell you is to tinker on the playground with possible suspect pieces of the data and run tests with just those pieces of struct & JSON one at a time.

Comment: You might find this tool useful if you have a sample of the valid json: https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/

Comment: @KennyGrant Oh that is all kinds of useful!

Comment: These two *"arrayToUnmarshalInto produces an empty slice"* and *"inspecting an individual UpdateConcert"* don't go together, do they? Either you have an empty slice and therefore there is no individual element that you can inspect, or your slice isn't empty.

Comment: @mkopriva I may be missing something here, but where are you understanding that I am inspecting a singular element? I should have defined it better; but `bytes, err := json.Marshal(concerts)` ... `concerts` is defined as `var concerts []UpdateConcert`  I also believe that the `fmt.Printf(str)` will produce the entirety of the stringified Marshalled bytes and that the `fmt.Printf(arrayToUnmarshalInto)` will print the slice of UpdateConcerts. Regardless of if the print statement is wrong or not; inspecting the elements in debug still shows that it does not work.

Comment: quote from your originla post: "However, the arrayToUnmarshalInto produces an empty slice. And when inspecting an individual UpdateConcert struct we see only default values and nil."

Comment: Ah, I understand now. I am sorry. What I was referring to was that I had tried to both marshal and unmarshal a singular `UpdateConcert` as well as a slice of `UpdateConcert`s. The original code was intended to work for a slice of `UpdateConcert`s; but currently I cannot unmarshal either.

Comment: If you comment out the `DomConcert` field from the `FullConcert` type, are the other fields still empty or are they marshaled/unmarshaled properly?

Comment: The data I was testing with had no data at the `FullConcert` level, I added some data and it would appear that regardless of if the `DomConcert` is there or not, it successfully unmarshals the `FullConcert` struct. Where it looks to be failing is specifically at the `*dom.Concert` portion.

Comment: So when you unmarshal the data, the resulting `arrayToUnmarshalInto` is not an empty slice but the field `arrayToUnmarshalInto[N].FullConcert.DomConcert` is `nil`? Or it's not `nil` it's just that all of it's fields are not being unmarshaled? Does `*dom.Concert` implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface?

Comment: Correct; `arrayToUnmarshalInto` is not an empty slice and `arrayToUnmarshalInto[N].FullConcert.DomConcert` is not `nil` but any field existing on `DomConcert` is either `""`, `nil`, or `0`. `dom.Concert` does not implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface. However; I am able to successfully do a `json.Marshal(concerts[N].FullConcert.DomConcert)` followed by a `json.Unmarshal(bytes, &concert)` and retrieve the data.

Comment: I'm sorry I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: Could we get a playground sample that reproduces the erroneous behaviour?

Comment: I have created a playground sample here: https://play.golang.org/p/z_dzP6FTU2

Comment: I don't understand the issue your playground sample is meant to be showing. It's not working because you are using private (lowercase) struct fields. Changing the fields to public (starting with an uppercase letter) makes the JSON marshal/unmarshal work as I would expect.